# Post method using Asp.Net WebApi controller with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

***Angular controller code:***

```
(function ()
{
myApp.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $scope.Emp = {};
    console.log("cont");

    $scope.Submit = function (Emp) {
        console.log("inside", $scope.Emp);
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '#/Test/Login',
            data: $scope.Emp,
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("response", response.data);
            //$window.location.href = '/Home/Display';
            if (response.data == "CORRECT UserName and Password") {
                console.log("if condition")
                $window.location.href = '/Test/Display';
            }
            else if (response.data == "INCORRECT UserName") {
                alert("INCORRECT UserName or Password");
            }
        })
    }
    $scope.Register = function () {
        $window.location.href = '/Test/Register';
    }
});
})(angular.module('myApp'));
```

***Angular Module Code:***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config('$StateProvider', '$UrlRouteProvider','$scope', '$LogProvider', '$http', '$location', '$window',
function ($StateProvider, $UrlRouteProvider, $scope, $http, $location, $window)
{
    $UrlRouteProvider.otherwise("/Login");

    $StateProvider
    .state('Login'),{
        url:'/Login',
        views:{
            '@':{
                templateUrl: "/Views/Home/Login.cshtml",
                controller: 'LoginController'
            }
        }
    }})
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what is the problem\error?

Answer (score 0):

You only declared but **didn't** inject `$LogProvider` in config after `$scope`. Declaration and injection have to be same and in exact order as well.

It should be like :

```
app.config('$StateProvider', '$UrlRouteProvider', '$scope', '$LogProvider', '$http', '$location', '$window',
function ($StateProvider, $UrlRouteProvider, $scope, $LogProvider, $http, $location, $window)
{
    $UrlRouteProvider.otherwise("/Login");

    $StateProvider
    .state('Login'),{
        url:'/Login',
        views:{
            '@':{
                templateUrl: "/Views/Home/Login.cshtml",
                controller: 'LoginController'
            }
        }
    }})
```

also there is `#` in your `url: '#/Test/Login',` check if you need it.

further, as per your code in question, it seems you don't require these much dependencies in config. In your code, I don't see any use of `$scope, $LogProvider, $http, $location, $window..`